# Update e insert desde 2 Contextos Diferentes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

tengo un problema: Tengo 2 bases de datos, la primera llamada DB1 y la segunda llamada DB2, en cada base tengo una tabla llamada "CatClasificación".

¿Es posible extraer toda la información de CatClasificación DB1 y hacer un insert o update a Clasificación DB2?
Estoy intentando hacerlo directo en una lista, como lo siguiente;

```
using var db1 = new DB1Context( );
var clasificacionlist = db.CatClasificacion.ToList( );

using var db2 = new DB2Context( );
db2.CatClasificacion.AddRange(clasificacionlist);
_=db1.SaveChanges( );
```

Pero al ejecutar el IDE me dice "No puede convertir de System.Collections.Generic.List<DB1.Clasificacion> a DB2.Models.Clasificación"

Agradeceria cualquier documentación o pasos a seguir, ya que no he encontrado algún ejemplo similar...

Comment: Si estás utilizando EF la forma adecuada de crear los *context* no es esa, pero me imagino que lo has puesto de esa forma a manera de ejemplo. ¿Has hecho alguna prueba? ¿Qué resultado has tenido?

Comment: Los context ya estan hechos, los genera automáticamente la consola del EF. Lo que puse en código ya sería la primera consulta de toda la tabla "CatClasificación" e intentar guardarla en mi DB2 context

Comment: Me refiero a que generalmente el DbContext necesita un grupo de opciones para poder inicializar la conexión con la base de datos. A veces también se puede utilizar haciendo `using (var context = new MyDbContext(ConnectionString)) {...etc...}`, pero siempre hay que asegurarse de que se invoque su `Dispose` y de que esté "vivo" el menor tiempo posible.

Comment: ¿Comprobaste si te funciona tu código? Debería funcionar. Puedes tener múltiples clases derivadas de DbContext que utilicen las mismas clases de modelo de datos, como tu `CatClasificación`.

Comment: Y cual es el problema,  el código funciona o no?

Comment: No funciona mi código, el IDE me dice "No puede convertir de System.Collections.Generic.List<DB1.Clasificacion> a DB2.Models.Clasificación"

Comment: entonces son modelos diferentes, la lista del DB1 tenes que mapear a DB2, usando automapper o a mano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que ambas entidades **CatClasificacion**, al estar en modelos diferentes y aunque tengan el mismo nombre y las mismas propiedades son tipos de datos diferentes y el compilador te avisa de eso, por tanto debes transformar la información.

```
var db1 = new DB1Context( );
var db2 = new DB2Context( );

var listaClasificacionDB1 = (from c in db1.CatClasificacion
                             select new Model2.CatClasificacion
                             {
                                Propiedad1 = c.Propiedad1,
                                Propiedad2 = c.Propiedad2,
                                PropiedadX = c.PropiedadX 
                             }).ToList();

db2.CatClasificacion.AddRange(listaClasificacionDB1);
db2.SaveChanges();
```

Aquí instanciamos los dos contextos **DB1Context** y **DB2Context** y convertimos todos los objetos **CatClasificacion** de **DB1Context** a objetos **CatClasificacion** pero de **DB2Context**, esto lo hacemos a través de **Linq** y en el **select** ponemos:

```
select new Model2.CatClasificacion
```

Aquí **Model2** sería el **namespace** correspondiente **DB2Context**, tú tendrías otro nombre de **namespace**(es solo para ilustrarte). Hay que anteponer el **namespace** ya que como ambas entidades **CatClasificacion** tienen el mismo nombre y el compilador detectará ambigüedad en los nombres y no sabrá si te refieres a la entidad de **DB1Context** o **DB2Context**.

Posteriormente a cada propiedad del objeto **DBContext** que estamos construyendo le ponemos su respectivo valor del otro **DBContext**:

```
Propiedad1 = c.Propiedad1,
Propiedad2 = c.Propiedad2,
PropiedadX = c.PropiedadX
```

Y ya por último añadimos al **DB2Context**, la lista de objetos del **DB1Context**

```
db2.CatClasificacion.AddRange(listaClasificacionDB1);
```

Y salvamos los cambios.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 1):

La [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/467746/228368) de [Japv](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/189826/japv) debería resolverte tu problema. No obstante te adiciono un punto más a tener en cuenta que te puede ayudar a resolverlo desde otra perspectiva.

Cuando tienes tipos de datos que debes utilizar en varios proyectos, o en varios contextos, y que son exactamente iguales, lo ideal es no repetir el código sino reutilizarlo. En este caso se trataría de crear la clase `CatClasificacion` en un *assembly* que esté accesible al resto de *assemblies* que lo utilizarán. Haciéndolo de esa forma haces que el código sea, además, más fácil de mantener. Si todo está en el mismo proyecto, como parece que es tu caso, entonces todo será más simple, sin necesidad de hacer copias de parámetros.

En lugar de tener dos clases de modelo iguales, una para uso con cada contexto, crea una sola clase de modelo y reutilízala en ambos. De esta forma no tendrás problemas al leer una lista de instancias a través de un contexto y luego adicionarla en el otro.

Por supuesto, esto no te será válido siempre porque si ambos contextos fueran exactos en cuanto a los modelos que utilizan entonces no estarías creando dos diferentes. Habrá casos donde la solución la oncontrarás únicamente aplicando lo que Japv te ha propuesto, leer los datos desde un contexto y luego "proyectarlos" (lo que hace el `select` en la consulta `LINQ` del código ejemplo) en el tipo de clase que espera el otro (el `new Model2.CatClasificacion` seguido de la inicialización de campos/propiedades entre las llaves `{ ...etc... }`).